# Activemq persistence for particular queue

Tags: persistence, activemq-classic, storage, jboss-amq

I have found the global configuration in activemq.xml for persisting the queues in the DB (persistenceadapter).

I have 5 queues running in my application and I want to persist only two queues, is there a way to that in activemq.xml ?

Regards,
BRK

Answer (score 1):

Go Ahead and use JMS delivery Mechanisms in such kind of situations , you can mark all the producers to a particular queue to be persistent and the others to be not persistent.

The destination policies do not have the persistence markup

Answer (score 0):

have a look at these [Destination Policies](http://activemq.apache.org/per-destination-policies.html), ActiveMQ has this special configurations for its Destinations(queue or topic).

It doesnt seem to possible what you are trying to achieve.

hope this helps!

Good luck!